# How do I change the ssd in a lenovo t560

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I just bought a lenovo t560 and it looks great and I also bought some ram and a bigger ssd which I wanted to put in my thinkpad.
The lenovo thinkpad t560 is closed at the bottom.
Do I have to remove the whole bottom or the keyboard?
Is it possible to open it?

Comment: You should look in the user manual.  You can find it on Lenovo's website.

Comment: You have to take the base off. https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t560_p50s_hmm_en_sp40k04930.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the hardware service manual for the T560 notebook](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t560_p50s_hmm_en_sp40k04930.pdf) the entire bottom panel comes off as a single piece.

Just unscrew the screws and remove the entire bottom (see page 65):

[image: Lenovo T560 Bottom]

Details on removing the drive are available starting on page 75, in the "*1040 Storage-drive stabilizer bar, internal storage drive, and hard disk
drive cable*" section.

Here's step one (after the bottom cover has been removed):

[image: T560 HDD Removal Step 1]

Comment: erf. Messing with perfection again, the older models needed you to take out ONE screw, slot out the caddy, and you could swap the drive. Much simpler :(

Comment: @JourneymanGeek The "best" things about many of these new Lenovo T-series are the ones with two batteries, one external, and one internal. Extra fun when it gets stuck in that "I'm not going to boot until you remove the battery and AC for 10 seconds" stuff that STILL happens with notebooks.  Luckily(?) they're kind enough to provide a tiny reset button for that internal battery, but good luck guessing that's there, if you're not expecting it. :)